# Changing code generated model naming convention

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, inheritance

When I create EF model, with a child and parent table, the code generation Model -> Database creates a naming convention that I do not like.

If I have Parent table, and Child table inherits from Parent table, for the database script it generates Parent1 table and Parent1_Child table, instead of Parent table and Child table.

How do I fix it, so that when the "Generate Database from Model" is used it generates the naming that I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the DDL generation template. According to the article, you make a T4 template of your own and just point EF to use your custom T4 for DDL generation instead of the original. I have personally never done this, but this article should give you some pointers: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560887.aspx

Essentially you could just copy the original T4 text and substitute your own naming conventions. Just make sure you also change your class generation templates to follow the same naming convention in the mapping section.

Comment: Now, to figure out what all these xsd files mean and how to actually make my own naming convention.